# How would I display a numeric component stacked with other components without looking likes its out of place?

Tags: usability, gui-design, design-patterns

We have multiple component types which stack on a form, the majority of components look OK (there is a lot of wasted space on most..).

Currently its looks something like this:
[image: bad]
Once there are components both above & below the numeric component it looks rather silly.

On the other hand, if i were to expand it to meet the other components, it would look even sillier than it already does, especially as the numbers rarely go above 1000:
[image: still bad]

Is there a smarter way of handling this, or am i just worrying over nothing?
The other components must remain wide due to spec requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using multi-select (because people often don't know how to use it) or drop-down select (because of the danger that if someone scrolls down while they still have the focus on the drop-down select, it can change the selected value without them realising). This article from [*A List Apart*, **Sensible Forms**](http://alistapart.com/article/sensibleforms), has some helpful advice and recommends against using multi-select.

I think your option one would work OK visually if you have a strong grid layout on your page that the "orphaned" numeric field lines up with.

Here is my redesign of your form, using radio buttons instead of the drop-down select, and checkboxes instead of the multi-select.

As you can see, it has its own internal "grid" which the elements fit into.

[image]

Comment: The only issue i have with this is alongside the _multiselect_ we also have a _filtered multiselect_, as the list of options in the system can be 50+ and scrolling through that many checkboxes for certain forms would be insane. Same for the radio buttons. Unless you can think of some way of filtering/paging these without blocking the user from viewing whats previously been selected, i cant imagine how to implement these two suggestions, as good as they may be.

Comment: "Unless you can think of some way of filtering/paging these without blocking the user from viewing whats previously been selected, i cant imagine how to implement these two suggestions, as good as they may be" - http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#the-filter2 - would this do as an example? Multiple select with filtering, multiple items per row and the first few choices are displayed in a text box.

Comment: @mgraham fantastic examples, thanks for that resource.

Comment: to select all checkboxes, I used this script:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228382/select-all-checkboxes-with-jquery

Comment: And to show or hide specific groups of checkboxes, you could give them a meaningful class, and progressively show or hide that class depending on other answers selected.